# Restrict custom API access to flutter app only

Tags: android, xcode, flutter, api, security

I have a custom API for my native Flutter app.
The API is used to create User accounts, so I cannot authenticate users individually based on user accounts.

Currently I use a universal API Key which is embedded into the app.

I use firebase, which requires to allow our SHA1 fingerprints in the web console. Can I use the same mechanism in my backend? Can I sign text/requests with the build certificate?

Or is there a different way to restrict API abuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check). It can also be used to protect the app's non-Firebase resources, such as self-hosted backends.

See for [Verify App Check tokens from a custom backend](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-resource-backend) details.